# fMRI Brain Image Registration in Matlab or Python between Patients

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, registration

So, I use [SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/) to register fMRI brain images between the same patient; however, I am having trouble registering images between patients.

Essentially, I want to register a brain atlas to a patient-specific scan, so that I can do some image patching. So register, then apply that warping and transformation to any number of images.

SPM was unsuccessful in such a registration. It cannot warp the atlas to be in the same brain shape as the patient brain.

Would software such as [freesurfer](http://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/) be good for this?? Or is there something better out there in either matlab or python (but preferably python)??

Thanks!

tylerthemiler

Comment: When asking in stackoverflow, try to phrase it in the form of a question. See the FAQ for more details.

Comment: I asked what software would be good for the problem described....seemed like a question to me.

Comment: Yes, I can understand what you are asking. I'm only suggesting you to change the format of the question. But I understand your point, although it is recommended that people ask in question format, most of the questions at the start page also doesn't follow this format. However, if you look at the most upvoted questions, you will see that they usually do follow this format.

Comment: I remember being able to do this in SPM. Look at the 'Normalize' step and reverse the inputs. Why do you say 'it cannot'? Posting in SPM forums might be a good idea too.

Comment: @Ashish: That was a good idea, exactly my intuition actually, unfortunately, it is simply not robust when using the patient space as reference (Atlas -> patient space as opposed to the other way around). Any help here would be amazing!

Comment: So, I got the normalize function in SPM to work for patient to ATLAS space (you just have to register first) but I cannot successfully go from ATLAS to patient space, even if I register before normalizing first...might need different software altogether for what I want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freesurfer segments and annotates the brain in the patient's native space, resulting in patient-specific regions, like [so](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2467665/freesurfer_segmentation.png).

I'm not sure what you mean by patching, or to what other images you'd like to apply this transformation, but it seems like the software most compatible for working with individual patient data, rather than normalized data across patients.

Comment: I figured it out but, bbregister (freesurfer) is good for registering to freesurfer anatomical space, but the only any-space-to-any space registration (non-rigid) I have found that is good is FNIRT by [FSL](http://www.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/) which is wrapped [NiPype](http://nipy.sourceforge.net/nipype/).

Cookie points for actually answering after MONTHS of this question being open :P

Answer (score 2):

There is a bulk of tools for image registration, e.g. look at http://www.nitrc.org  under "Spatial transformation" -> "Registration".  Nipype is indeed a nice Python module which wraps many of those (e.g. FSL, Freesurfer, etc) so you could explore different available tools within somewhat unified interface.

Besides those well known (SPM, FSL, AFNI) also you could give a try to somewhat less known but very powerful CMTK (http://www.nitrc.org/projects/cmtk) which comes with non-linear registration(s), population-based template construction, many other features and SRI24 atlas.  Such script as asegment_sri24  could be used for a quick start with registering/reslicing each subject using labels available in SRI24 atlas.

To start using CMTK (or dozens of other neuroimaging software) in a matter of minutes I would recommend you to look at http://neuro.debian.net -- the platform to allow very easy deployment of (maintained) neuroscience software.  FSL, AFNI, CMTK, SRI24 atlas etc are available there upon your demand ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) is made for this kind if purpose. A Python wrapper exists ([Paul Novotny](http://www.paulnovo.org/) distributes binaries for Ubuntu on his site), but this is mainly C++. If you work under Linux then it is quite simple to compile if you are familiar with cmake.

As this toolkit is a very low-level framework I can advise you to try [elastix](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/index.php) which is a command line utility allowing one to make registration on picture using multiscale Bspline dense registration.

Another interesting tool based on Maxwell demons and improved with diffeomorphic capabilities is [MedINIRA](http://www-sop.inria.fr/asclepios/software/MedINRIA/).

Answer (score 1):

Along SPM's lines, you can use [IBSPM](http://www.thomaskoenig.ch/Lester/ibaspm.htm). It was developed to solve exactly that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANTs software, or u can use Python within 3dSclicer for template registration. 
However, I did mane template registration in SPM and I recommend it for fMRI data better than ITK or Slicer.

I found these links very helpful :) let me know if you need more help.

https://fmri-training-course.psych.lsa.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Preprocessing-of-fMRI-Data-in-SPM-12-Lab-1.pdf

https://nipype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/examples/fmri_spm.html